# Past tense. He watched / has watched / had watched?

Tags: past-tense

I don't understand. Is it okay to use HAD + ED ?

He watched is fine for me. He has/had watched is weird, I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You are referring to the present perfect and past perfect tenses

Use the present perfect tense (has + [verb]ed) to indicate that something started occuring in the past and is still currently happening:

> She has lived here for two years.

Use the past perfect tense to indicate that something started happening in the past but no longer is happening because of or at the same time as a second event:

> She had lived here for two years before moving away.

You could use the past simple tense if you don't refer to the event that caused her to stop living here (moving away):

> She lived here for two years.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing tense and aspect. Perfect aspect in English is indicated as follows:

a form of the verb "have" (perhaps preceded by a modal) indicating time (past, present, or future), person (first, second, or third), number (singular or plural), voice (active or passive), progressive aspect or not, and mode (conditional or not)

with the next element of the verb being a "perfect" participle, either "been" to show the passive or that of the substantive verb. If "been" is the next element of the verb, the final element of the verb may be either a perfect or a present participle of the substantive verb.

In other words, "have" is used as an auxiliary to indicate grammatical nuances of meaning in the verb while the final participle indicates the root meaning of the verb.

Variations in the use of auxiliary verbs ("have," "be," and the modals) convey in English what would be conveyed by inflections in a heavily inflected language. When used as an auxiliary, "have" conveys a purely grammatical message, not a substantive one.

One thing that can be confusing is that passives are formed using "be" as an auxiliary and the "perfect" participle. In that case, the participle is frequently called the "passive" participle.

Another thing that can be confusing is that both "have" and "be" can be used together as auxiliary verbs.

All I can say is that memorizing these rules for constructing verbs from modals, auxiliaries, and participles is no harder than memorizing Latin conjugations of irregular verbs. But recognizing that "have" used as an auxiliary verb does not alter the meaning inherent in the root meaning of the final participle may help you understand the basic meaning being conveyed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about is as a kind of "past in the past" tense.

So, imagine we have a courtroom case (taking place in 2019) to determine who is fault for damages after somebody crashed a ferry boat in 2017, and a lawyer is trying to determine if the captain of the boat had done all the required training.

> Lawyer: "Has the captain of the boat watched the mandatory training video?"
>
> Ferry company CEO: "Yes, he has watched the video."

This would be true if the captain watched the training video in 2018 - *after* crashing the boat!  That's no use.  We are not interested in whether or not he watched it prior to the time of speaking, we are interested in whether or not he watched it prior to crashing the boat.  So instead we need to say:

> Lawyer: "Had the captain of the boat watched mandatory training (prior to the incident)?"
>
> Ferry company CEO: "Yes, he had watched the video."

So it indicates something which occured in the past not just compared to the time the speaker is speaking, but which is (further) in the past compared to the (past) time the speaker is speaking *about*.